# Outlook forwarded meeting invitation

Tags: windows-7, iphone

I was receipient of an outlook meeting invite which I forwarded to others adding my text. It shows up on other receipients that I have send this email as modification to the meeting invitation and comes up as if I have sent on behalf of the originator of the meeting. Can the old invitees and orignator see the added text to this email/meeting ?

Also this outlook meeting was forwarded by iphone ios7

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with early versions of iOS7 that would cause iOS devices to take ownership of a meeting that was accessed through Exchange services. Upgrading to the 7.1 fixed the issue.

The exchange server would actually make the iOS user the owner of the meeting in it's database so only they could make changes to the meeting. If you were to send an "update" then everyone else would definitely get the notification with the changes that you had made. Otherwise, I don't think it updated automatically beyond the owner.